Save files with the same name in the same folder (in numerical order)
WIN11.
AFAIK it's not possible for two files with the same name to be saved in the same location (unless they don't actually share the same name), so I'm looking for a workaround.
I have two separate folders that I'd like to merge into one.
The Folder1's files are named Result_1.pdf, Result_2.pdf, ... Result_35.pdf.
The Folder2's files are also named Result_1.pdf, Result_2.pdf, ... Result_27.pdf  (the number of files in both folders rarely match).
Folder1!Result_1 is not the same file as Folder2!Result_1, and so on.
My goal is to find a way to save them in just one folder, and in a way that keeps them in numerical, not lexicographical order. This is because later I will load this folder to PowerQuery where I'll need the rows of data to be sorted in a way that respects the numerical order of each file.
Folder1!Result_1
Folder2!Result_1
Folder1!Result_2
Folder2!Result_2
...

I had this issue when I was working with just Folder1 as well (I first split the column by the _ delimiter to leave the numbers isolated).
Is there a way to bypass this?

Just normalise the numbers to N significant digits with Result first. eg Result_0001-Folder0001 to Result_0010-Folder0010 matches your implied ordering


Rename all the files in Folder 1, e.g., first.pdf -> first.pdf_folder1.pdf, second.pdf -> second.pdf_folder1.pdf.   Open a command prompt in Folder 1 and enter the following:
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "%a_folder1.pdf"

Do the same in folder 2, changing the statement to:
for %a in (*.*) do ren "%a" "%a_folder2.pdf"

Now merge the folders.


Yes, the file extension is repeated in the filename, but causes no issue.

If I understand your requirement you want something like (Please correct me if I am wrong)

This is simply done using copy or move but I have used copy so as not to destroy the source while testing.
@echo off
for /l %%c in (1,1,9) do copy Folder1\Result_%%c.pdf merged\Folder1!Result_00%%c.pdf >nul
for /l %%c in (10,1,99) do copy Folder1\Result_%%c.pdf merged\Folder1!Result_0%%c.pdf >nul
for /l %%c in (1,1,9) do copy Folder2\Result_%%c.pdf merged\Folder2!Result_00%%c.pdf >nul
for /l %%c in (10,1,99) do copy Folder2\Result_%%c.pdf merged\Folder2!Result_0%%c.pdf >nul

To include move all files from folder 2 to folder1 and remove folder 2 use
@echo off

for /l %%a in (1,1,2) do (
REM First normalise all single digit files to 2 digits
for /l %%b in (1,1,9) do ren Folder%%a\Result_%%b.pdf Folder%%a!Result_0%%b.pdf 2>nul
REM second rename all remaining double digits
for /l %%c in (10,1,99) do ren Folder%%a\Result_%%c.pdf Folder%%a!Result_%%c.pdf 2>nul
)

REM Move 2 to 1
move Folder2\*.* Folder1
REM remove folder 2
rd folder2
pause

